# Is it possible to get current charset of OS in broswer for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

Rencently I'm using [lingala/zip4j](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j) lib to handle `.zip` files uploaded by users.
It seems that UTF-8 would be the default charset for reading inside file structure.
This will cause exceptions if a `.zip` file is compressed in a OS not running UTF-8 as default charset.

Seems that [CharsetDetector](https://tika.apache.org/0.8/api/org/apache/tika/parser/txt/CharsetDetector.html) of [Apache Tika](https://github.com/apache/tika) cannot detect correct charset of filename String of `FileHeader` instances too.

So is it possible to detect **default charset of user OS** (not the charset of loaded HTML) for JavaScript running in browser?

Comment: Doesn't it depend more on the tool used to create the ZIP file than on the OS default charset? As far as I'm aware, the ZIP tool should use either IBM-437 or UTF-8 for file name encoding, but there seem to be plenty of tools that don't respect the standard.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It can't be expected that users would use a "standard tool" to create ZIP file. From my experience that most tools would use OS's default charset to encode inner filenames. So the best way to solve this problem I can imagine is depending on that feature.